# how can I use the pure docker data image inside kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In docker world, we can use pure docker image and use `--volumes-from` to connect it with container, how this works in the kubernetes

Docker image could be html files like

```
FROM scratch
COPY html /www
```

How can I mount it to the nginx pod?

BTW: Surely I can turn docker pure data image to use `busybox` as base image, then copy the data out using initContainers, which make the image 1M bigger, here try to see whether it is possible in k8s world

Comment: That approach doesn't make sense: a Docker image is fundamentally _executable_, and a collection of HTML files isn't.  In general there's not a good way for one container to access another's files, especially if one of the containers doesn't have tools like `cp` available.  Could you `COPY` these files into an image `FROM nginx` instead?

Comment: Surely I can use `FROM busybox`, but try to see whether we can use docker data image directly

Comment: seems not possible use pure docker data image, so I use @DavidMaze's solution from `FROM nginx`

Comment: @DavidMaze if u can combine your comments as one answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Docker's named volumes, volume mounts in Kubernetes never copy anything *into* the volume.  You occasionally see tricks with Docker Compose setups where a Docker named volume is mounted over two containers, with the expectation that static files will be copied into the volume from one of them to be served by the other; this just doesn't work in Kubernetes unless you copy the files yourself.

For the setup you show, you have a collection of files you want to serve, and you want to have the standard `nginx` image serve them.  Instead of trying to copy files between images, you can have a unified image that starts `FROM nginx` and contains your files:

```sh
FROM nginx
COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
# Base image provides a suitable default CMD and other setup
```

You don't need any sort of volume to run this.  Just specify it as the `image:` in your Deployment spec, and all of the files to be served are already compiled into the image.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [`volumes` and `volumeMounts`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes).

### UPD:

html file to mount:

```
$ cat index.html
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
```

Create configMap with the content of the file:

```
$ kubectl create configmap nginx-index-html-configmap --from-file=index.html
  configmap/nginx-index-html-configmap created
```

nginx pod file:

```
$ cat nginx-with-config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
        name: nginx-config
        subPath: index.html
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      configMap:
        name: nginx-index-html-configmap
```

Creating the pod:

```
$ kubectl create -f nginx-with-config.yaml
  pod/nginx created
```

Checking nginx serves the file:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx -- curl 127.0.0.1
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
```

### UPD2:

You can have everything in one big happy file, no need to prep anything in advance:

```
$ cat nginx-with-config.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-index-html-configmap-2
data:
  index.html: |
    <h1>HELLO 2!</h1>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx2
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
        name: nginx-config
        subPath: index.html
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-config
      configMap:
        name: nginx-index-html-configmap-2
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f nginx-with-config.yaml
  configmap/nginx-index-html-configmap-2 created
  pod/nginx2 created
```

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx2 -- curl 127.0.0.1
  <h1>HELLO 2!</h1>
```

Comment: can u show examples, i saw git works before, so might work for docker image as well

Comment: added an example

Comment: thx for updating, this needs to be prepared in advance

Comment: in advance to what?

Comment: made another update to show how to have everything as one file, including the html code